# amplifier for 10V LED dimmer control using Raspberry Pi

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, raspberry-pi, led-driver, dimmer

My problem is I need to have an amplifier circuit design - schematic + components BOM with specific model information that is able to provide a dimmable output signal (Vout) 0.2-10V <0.8A for a set of 8x LED drivers using Raspberry Pi PWM GPIO pin which is able to provide input signal (VG) of 0-3.3V <16 mA.

My understanding is that this can be achieved using MOSFET amplifier circuit.  I hired an LED vendor to design such a circuit and when he tested in the workshop he was unable to lower the Vout to <1 V, and consequently his circuit was unable to switch off the LED lights.  The MOSFET he selected was a D882 P33.  The LED lights need to have a low signal of 0-0.25A in order to turn OFF.  A negative signal will turn the lights back ON again.

I did some workshop testing using a circuit similar to the one below obtained from an online course from [ECE UCSB](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/rodwell/Classes/ece2c/labs/Lab_2_2C_2007.pdf), and reproduced the same problem.  I replaced the RBPI using a universal AC adapter 3V 500mA to not damage the RBPI during testing.

During my testing there were four problems I encountered

1) I was also unsuccessful to lower the Vout to <1A using two MOSFET models BF506 and 2N3906.  I believe that this requires a MOSFET with RDSON of <0.15Ohms and I couldnt find this value on the datasheet specifications for these models.

2) I was unsuccessful to establish a minimum drain voltage using R1, R2 resistors and was confused by the capacitor in the VG front end of the circuit.  When I connected a 100k Ohm resistor for R1 and a tiny resistance <100Ohms for R2 and the VCC connected to the VG front-end circuit, I was unable to control the voltage VG and the voltage would shoot up to >4V. I then removed the R1, R2 and the VCC connections and was then able to control the voltage.

3) I was not able to use the circuit when the capacitor was connected. Again the voltage VG would shoot up to 3.3V and I could not adjust at all, so I removed the capacitor.

4) The behavior of the VG and Vout was inverted from what was expected. When I provided a 0.9V signal VG, I received a 2.05V Vout, and for a 3.3V VG --> 4.32V out.  This is opposite to what was expected which is for the higher VG voltage to produce a low output signal Vout.

I'm adding a photo of the LED drivers. The vendor provided two types of models in the system. I realize in the original problem description I described for a single LED driver, but actually the system is 8x drivers connected in parallel.  Of the 8x drivers there are at least 2x different models, I have not opened to inspect for the other 6x.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: which LED dimmerr?

Comment: Why do you seem to want an analog solution and not a PWM one?

Comment: (Re:Chris) I am looking for a soution that works with digital PWM GPIO input signal from RBPI, if the way I draw looks like its analog then that would be my mistake. I am learning as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than explain or fix the circuit you show which does not have a chance of working I will show what will work.

Specs:

0 to 3.3V source ( low Z) must be amplified to 0 to 10 out.
Load Impedance: assumed high   Z.

Easiest solution is a rail to rail in & out (RRIO) Op Amp (OA) with a 10V supply. (LDO)

Gain= 10/3.3=3.03 ( round up )

Resistor range:  100k preferred.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgYCZu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a discrete solution from 0.1V to ~10V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE9H5Q.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I have a few follow-up questions to understand how to interpret the sketch. Just now I opened in CircuitLab and tried to understand by using the DC Sweep but was unsuccessful, all of the voltages showed negative values.

Questions

Comment: CLab is lame, I never use it http://tinyurl.com/y5bwrbah

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I have a few follow-up questions to understand how to interpret the sketch. I haven't yet researched OpAmp circuits so I need some time to study.  Just now I opened in CircuitLab and tried to understand by using the DC Sweep but was unsuccessful, all of the voltages showed negative values.

Questions
1) could you label Vout 0-10V, and VCC source 12V?
2) What should the voltage be to the input to the JFET? The way I read it the source 0-3.3V is before the R1 100 kOhm resistance and the input to the U1 JFET is some tiny value, is that correct?

Comment: no.  the circuit you show cannot work as a linear amp.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the simulator on falstad. I have a few more questions on the differences between the falstad and the Clab circuit.

1) the falstad circuit doesn't show the top part of U2, can I ignore that part?
2) whre is the RBPI signal ? before or after the 100k resistance? If the RBPI signal is the little line that is going from 0-3.3V then what is the 40HZ source supposed to represent?

Comment: That simulates full scale input , ramp sweep

Comment: For feedback, I have tested and verified on breadboard with no load single channel and able to amplify from 0-5V to 0-10V using Arduino UNO and LM358 DIP. So seems in principle works.  I will try again with LED driver load on and also to use the RBPI 0-3.3V.  Only variant is that I used 20k, 10k, 10k resistors instead of the proposed 200k, 100k, 100k resistors. Theoretical gain is same for both cases.  I submitted a feedback vote for the answer FYI but maybe the system doesn't take my vote. Thanks again!